# Mathdesign font installation

Tags: fonts, tex-core, installing-fonts

I want to use the free Garamond for LaTeX and found the `mathdesign`-Package.

Now I have to install the nessecary font-files like it is described in the readme-document:

> You can find these free text fonts  on CTAN:
>
> CTAN directory of Adobe Utopia      : fonts/utopia
>   CTAN directory of URW Garamond      : nonfree/fonts/urw/garamond
>   CTAN directory of Bitstream Charter : fonts/charter

I searched a lot for these files but couldn't find anything that looks like something useable.

Could you please lighten my mind?

Comment: Which distribution and which OS do you have?

Comment: I use MikTeX 2.9 on Windows 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under MiKTeX, you'll have to:

1. Create a local TeXMF directory, say `LocalTeXMF`. This is where you should put local additions which are not part of the distribution.
2. Register it as ‘Root’ with `MiKTeX Settings`, both as administrator and as user:[image]
3. Download from the [CTAN fonts directory](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/urw/garamond) the contents of the `./URW.Garamond` subdirectory. You don't need the readme_garamond nor the ugmfnst.zip files.
4. Install the 4 `.afm` files in `LocalTeXMF\fonts\afm\urw\garamond`. Likewise install the 4 `pfb` files in  `LocalTeXMF\fonts\type1\urw\garamond`. The `pfm` files are not necessary: they're binary versions of the .afm files  used by Windows. Should you install them, they would be naturally be in  `LocalTeXMF\fonts\pfm\urw\garamond`.
5. Unzip `ugm.zip` at the root of `LocalTeXMF`. You don't need the `dvips` directory (the relevant file is already contained in `mathdesign`).
6. Update the FNDB.
7. Run from the command line `updmap --admin --verbose`, to update the database of Postscript fonts.

That's all (!!!).

However, I would recommend to install, from MiKTeX Package Manager (as administrator) the `garamondx` package, which is  an extension of URW Garamond No8 containing real smallcaps (in regular, italic, bold and bold italic variants), old-style numbers and full system of f-ligatures. To use them within `mathdesign`, you have to write in your preamble:

```
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
```

In this case, all you have to do is to run `updmap` as before, after installation.

Comment: Thanks for that detailled information! In deed I _had_ to install the pfb-files for not getting errors ;-) But now everything works fine!